# Switching Joomla Templates based on user's browser

Tags: templates, joomla

Is there is way to automatically switch the default template used in joomla based on the users browser? For instance, I am currently using Gantry framework for one of my websites, it would be a tonne of work to accommodate IE6, 7 and 8 into this framework, I was wondering if there's a script that will detect the users browser, say IE7, and if the user is using this browser Joomla automatically switches to a template that is compatible with that browser?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a way, it is called "Conditional Comments".
Conditional comments are a special type of HTML comments that work as conditions, and they are mostly used to check Internet Explorer version (because of css-compatibility).

Vocabulary:

- lte: less than or equal to
- gte: greater than or equal to
- lt: less than
- gt: greater than
- !: not

This is the use of conditional comments:

```
<!--[if <something from vocabulary> IE <version>]>
code
<![endif]-->
```

Let's see some examples

```
<!--[if IE]>
You are certainly running Internet Explorer<br />
<![endif]-->

<!--[if !IE]>
You are certainly NOT running Internet Explorer<br />
<![endif]-->

<!--[if IE 6]>
You are certainly running Internet Explorer version 6<br />
<![endif]-->

<!--[if lte IE 6]>
You are certainly running Internet Explorer and it's version is lower or equal to 6<br />
<![endif]-->

<!--[if gte IE 6]>
You are certainly running Internet Explorer and it's version is greater or equal to 6<br />
<![endif]-->

<!--[if lt IE 6]>
You are certainly running Internet Explorer and it's version is lower than 6<br />
<![endif]-->

<!--[if gt IE 6]>
You are certainly running Internet Explorer and it's version is greater than 6<br />
<![endif]-->
```

> it would be a tonne of work to accommodate IE6, 7 and 8 into this framework

In fact, joomla templates are made of some css files, named template.css, template.ie6.css, template,ie7.css, etc.

this is not a tonne of work, because the template.css contains the FULL template css, and template.ie#.css files contains only those rules which need to be overrided in order to work with a specific version of IE.

Then, in the template index file, there are some Conditional Comments that switch the css according to the browser you are using

SOURCE: http://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html